# Memory managnment command in eclipse.ini ignored

Tags: eclipse, memory-management, ram

I'm making a java game (minecraft clone) and I require to store quite some data in RAM,
around 1024Mb.

However I tried setting my required parameter in eclipse.ini but those are not being used by eclipse's JVM.

eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-javaagent:lombok.jar
-Xbootclasspath/a:lombok.jar
```

as you can see I should get more RAM but my test app show me something else :

```
memory with 500 sectors :
##### Heap utilization statistics [MB] #####
Used Memory:102
Free Memory:50
Total Memory:152
Max Memory:247
```

Memory is still blocked at 256MB.

any Ideas?

configuration : 
windows 7 64 bits, eclipse indigo 32 bits, JDK1.6 32 bits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've changed the amount of memory available *to run Eclipse*.

To change the amount of memory available to your program, you'll want to add `-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m` to the *VM Arguments* section in your run/debug configuration (look under the *Arguments* tab).

Comment: thanks, it was indeed in the VM argument section, It took me quite some time to find where to access them^^.

right click on program.java>run as>run configuration...